# Player for long recordings

Tags: itunes, audio

I have recordings which last many hours.
I want to focus on some points of the recording.

iTunes is not accurate for it.

Is there something in the settings for iTunes to allow for more precise playback timeline?

Does the mini player has a longer time axis. 
I do not know how to customize it at the moment.

Alternatively **What is a good program for playing long audio records when you need to focus on some instance during the recording?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the free and open source [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) sound recorder.

It is a powerful recorder, editor, and converter.

You can find a version that is backwards compatible with macs running much older versions of OS X.

It has a steeper learning curve than QuickTime’s or iTunes audio recording feature, but it is far more powerful and better suited for longer recordings where editing is needed.

Here is a Sample:

[image]